# How to create anti update packages for Sitecore update packages?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I need to compare a Sitecore .update package(example, abc.update) and a Sitecore instance, maybe the serialized version of the instance and create an anti update package(example, abc.anti.update). The anti update package will basically take a backup from the Sitecore instance of all the matching items which exist in the .update package.

Answer (score 1):

During the package installation, not all commands from the package are going to be executed. For example, if you have a change field command but on your solution, the field have the target value, the command from the package will be ignored.
Thus, if you just generate anti-upgrade package it will not always be correct.

BTW: real rollback package is generated during installation. It is saved in website/temp/__updateHistore//rollbackPackage.rlb
Using some API from Sitecore.Update.dll the package can be converted to a real rollback update package.